# Cors implementation in .Net Core 3.1 project with Oracle Database Host

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-3.1

Only one HOST can connect to the API, in this case it is an Oracle server.

I added Cors as per Microsoft docs, still other HOST can connect to my API. Has anyone tried to add an Oracle Database HOST? Is there something wrong with the configuration?

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://oraas1111.net:1001")
                                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                                           .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
        } 
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("CorsPolicy");
            });
        }
```

Controller.cs

```
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class Controller : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Service/[action]")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Request>> Update(Request data)
        {

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/GET_Service/[action]")]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the startup class can you move AddControllers and AddHttpClient after the policy? Does this work?

Comment: It works but only partially, not as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move services.AddCors() to the top, before AddControllers()

Comment: It works but only partially, not as expected. I thought Cors would disable everything except the list of hosts that are in CorsPolicy. Unfortunately, the blockade is only when I am on the website, for example test.com and I want to run some API function from it (GET, POST). When I hit my API directly from the browser, Cors doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to block it?